# C++ programs using Octave libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, octave

I try to use in my c++ project libraries from Octave. 
Unfortunately, I am not able to build program.
I use Windows 7 64 bit, Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2 and gcc 4.6.2.

My steps:

1. Downloaded Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2.exe 
   (http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Windows%20binaries/Octave%203.6.4%20for%20Windows%20MinGW%20installer/Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2_20130408.7z/download)

Which I installed in C:\Octave. I have added the address of the bin folder of octave to the environmental variable PATH.

2. Downloaded mingw32-gcc-4.6.2-release-c,c++,fortran-sjlj-FINAL.7z
   and installed in C drive. I have added the address of the bin folder of mingw to the environmental variable PATH.
3. Tried to compile simple example main.cpp (or example from http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html#Standalone-Programs)

.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  return 0;
}
```

4. I used makefile:

.

```
OCTAVE_INCLUDE=C:\Octave\Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2\include\octave-3.6.4

all: test

clean:
    -rm test.o test

test: test.o
    mkoctfile --link-stand-alone -o test test.o

test.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c -I$(OCTAVE_INCLUDE) -I$(OCTAVE_INCLUDE)octave -o test.o main.cpp
```

So, we have

hdf5.h: No such file or directory
regex.h: No such file or directory

but they are in C:\Octave\Octave3.2.4_gcc4.4.0\include\

I do not understand where is my mistake.

Comment: Well, you say the header the file is in "C:\Octave\Octave3.2.4_gcc4.4.0\include\"
and you are telling `g++` to search for header files in "C:\Octave\Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2\include\octave-3.6.4"
and in "C:\Octave\Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2\include\octave-3.6.4octave", neither of which
is "C:\Octave\Octave3.2.4_gcc4.4.0\include\".

Comment: Mike, how can I tell the compiler that nessesary headers are in "C:\Octave\Octave3.2.4_gcc4.4.0\include\" ?

Comment: The way you are already doing it! - with the `-I<directory>` option. Just specify the right `<directory>`(s).

Comment: I understand, but I dont know how can I specify two pathes for including in my case

Comment: Use multiple `-I<dir>` options. The compiler will search them in the
order specified until success or final failure. It looks like you basically don't understand how to use GCC and GNU Make,
and it's beyond the purposes of Stackoverflow to fix that.
[Here is a fairly sound beginner's tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html).
For authoritative documentation, [here is the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) and
[here is the GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Comment: the tool `mkoctfile` (in your case with --link-stand-alone) takes care of -I, -L and -l

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was an issue with my gcc version. It seems likely that it was incompatible with the version used to compile octave.

The corrected makefile is below:

```
OCTAVE_INCLUDE=C:\Octave\Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2\include

all: test

clean:
    -rm test.o test

test: test.o
    mkoctfile --link-stand-alone -o test test.o

test.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c -I$(OCTAVE_INCLUDE) -I$(OCTAVE_INCLUDE)\octave-3.6.4 -o test.o main.cpp
```